# Can I change the data source for my output jobs in Upsolver

Tags: sqlake, upsolver

Upsolver output is delayed/stuck - We changed the data source for some outputs to a new one. The odd thing is that the "delay" column in the outputs page seems to point to the old data sources and delay is not changing. Why is this happening, shouldn't the output now reflect the new data source and proceed ingesting data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance stop the "old" data source before the old output version has managed to stop? In general when you edit an output and change the source, you need to let the old data source run until you see that the version has completed. This is because we still have tasks that we need to finish running until the time the datasource was stopped.
So, please run the old datasources until you see under the version history tab that the previous version is completed. This should change the delay from the previous version to the current version and you will see the correct delays.
For example if you goto the output, under Version History tab, it should show two versions. Please rerun it until version 1 has completed